# SpringBootApplication exclude when ComponentScanning other @SpringBootApplications

Tags: java, solr, spring-boot, component-scan

I'm having some difficulty preventing Spring Boot from auto configuring some classes (in this example: SolrAutoConfiguration). To illustrate I've setup a much reduced example:

https://github.com/timtebeek/componentscan-exclusions

In reality there's some 20+ internal `@SpringBootApplication` projects, each with their own dependencies coming together. (Not ideal / not my idea, but hard to move away from now.)

The problem arises because multiple subprojects are using Solr 5.2.1, but Spring Boot is only compatible with 4.x. In the final application (module-b in the example) I want to import all `@SpringBootApplication` classes across all my modules, while preventing `SolrAutoConfiguration` from running:

```
@ComponentScan("project") // Broad scan across all company jars
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SolrAutoConfiguration.class }) // Failing exclude
public class ModuleBApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ModuleBApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

This fails, because any instance of `@SpringBootApplication` picked up through the `@ComponentScan` without the specific exclude, still loads `SolrAutoConfiguration`.

What can I do to properly exclude a auto configuration class when combining multiple `@SpringBootApplication` classes?

I've already tried to work with `excludeFilters` on my final `@SpringBootApplication`, but that hasn't yet lead to a solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.3.0.M3 introduced functionality to exclude autoconfiguration using properties:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3.0-M3-Release-Notes

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration
```

Note that it should say `spring.autoconfigure.exclude`, not `excludes` as in the release notes.

This helps prevent Spring Boot from loading autoconfig classes in the presence of multiple `@EnableAutoConfiguration`/`@SpringBootApplication` annotations.

Answer (score 3):

Currently I think it's not possible. The issues [gh-2939](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2939) and [gh-2435](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2435) relate to exactly this problem.