# spring boot compilation cannot find symbol componentscan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda

i am getting connot find symbol component scan error in my small spring boot project. any idea where i am going wrong.

**base class:**

```
@ComponentScan("com.example.test.lambda")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**config class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Profile("lambda")
public class Config {

    
    @Bean
    public HandlerMapping handlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public HandlerAdapter handlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver() {
        return new HandlerExceptionResolver() {

            @Override
            public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

**dependency tree:**

it shows spring context classes are already loaded..

```
+- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
```

**error:**

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project spring-boot-lambda: Compilation failure
[ERROR] spring-boot-lambda-test-jenkins/lambda-service/spring-boot-lambda/src/main/java/com/example/test/lambda/Application.java:[7,2] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class ComponentScan
```

Comment: Hard to say with code snippets. Did you import it?

Comment: i also finding it tough to  get the issue.. i actually checked out the code from a open repo

Comment: it may cannot resolve a dependency, can you update the Application class to see package and imports too?

Comment: Can you share the repo rather than code snippet? That way we can compile the project ourselves.

Comment: Repo is the simplest version..not using component scan

Comment: git clone https://github.com/gemerick/spring-boot-lambda.git
git checkout lambda

Answer (score 0):

This is a redundant declararion... SpringBootApplication also provides you a componentScan... if you really want to use @ComponentScan change your @SpringBootApplication for something smaller like a @Configuration....

But doing that you gonna loose all the auto-configuration provided by Springboot.

[Springboot configuration annotation explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407836/4499068)

**Update**

I've cloned your repo and it build well, without any fuhter changing anything but your class configuration

[Maven build succesfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu8Hd.png)

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that i know.. even if i want to use import.. it is saying cannot find symbol.. that is strange to me.. i am declaring multiple files with RestController annotation but it is only taking up one controller in the context.. cannot read any other controller..

Comment: Please see the update I made to my post with the considerations

Comment: Maybe you have to commit and push your changes so i can evaluate... Because i saw that the build error is being made in a package that does not exist now on your HEAD.

I dont have this package on my local source of your code _/src/main/java/com/example/test/lambda/Application.java_